# python 3.4 spirograph error

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
from turtle import*                                                                      
from math import*

def Xcord(R,r,p,t):  

    x= (R-r) * cos(t) - (r+p) * cos((R-r)//r*t)

def Ycord (R,r,p,t):

    y= (R-r) * sin(t) - (r+p) * sin((R-r)//r*t)

def t_iter(R,r,p):

      t=0
      down()
      goto(Xcord(R,r,p,t),Ycord(R,r,p,t))
      while (t < 2 * pi):
          t = t+.01
          Xcord(R,r,p,t)
          Ycord(R,r,p,t)
          up()
      return

def main():

      R=100
      r=4
      p=int(input("Please enter a number between 10 and 100: "))
      if p < 10 or p > 100:
            input(" Incorrect value of p!")
      t_iter(R,r,p)
      input("Hit enter to close porgram")
      bye()

main()
```

I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:/Users/Coscio/Desktop/spirals.py", line 31, in <module>
    main()

  File "C:/Users/Coscio/Desktop/spirals.py", line 27, in main
    t_iter(R,r,p)

  File "C:/Users/Coscio/Desktop/spirals.py", line 13, in t_iter
    goto(Xcord(R,r,p,t),Ycord(R,r,p,t))

  File "<string>", line 1, in goto

  File "D:\Python\lib\turtle.py", line 1774, in goto
    self._goto(Vec2D(*x))

TypeError: type object argument after * must be a sequence, not NoneType
```

Comment: `Xcord` and `Ycord` both implicitly `return None`.

Comment: I not understanding how they are returning none when both are defined and called

Comment: You need explicit return statements. `return x` and `return y` in those methods. Also, `t_iter` is returning None too..

Comment: ...because you haven't told them to return anything.

Comment: so in my function t_iter it should be in the while loop return Xcord and return Ycord

Comment: No, because if you `return` in the `while` loop the function will end.

Comment: def t_iter(R,r,p):
    t=0
    down()
    goto(Xcord(R,r,p,t), Ycord(R,r,p,t))
    while (t < 2 * pi):
        t = t+.01
        Xcord(R,r,p,t)
        Ycord(R,r,p,t)
        up()
    return Xcord()
    return Ycord()

Comment: so I put the return Xcord() and return Ycord() after the while loop and it's still resulting in the same error. I'm not understanding how its returning none

Comment: Hi guys I got the program to run by changing the Xcord and Yord def to a return but now im getting an type error saying a float is required

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from turtle import*

from math import*

def Xcord(R,r,p,t):

        return (R-r) * cos(t) - (r+p) * cos((R-r)//r*t)

def Ycord (R,r,p,t):
    return (R-r) * sin(t) - (r+p) * sin((R-r)//r*t)

def t_iter(R,r,p):
    t=0
    up()
    Xcord(R,r,p,t)
    Ycord(R,r,p,t)
    while (t < 2 * pi):
        t = t+.01
        goto(Xcord(R,r,p,t),Ycord(R,r,p,t))
        down()
    return float(Xcord(R,r,p,t))
    return float(Ycord(R,r,p,t))

def validate():
    while True:
        p=int(input("Please enter a number between 10 and 100: "))
        if p >= 10 or p <= 100:
            break
    return p


def main():
    speed(0)
    R=100
    r=4
    p = validate()
    t_iter(R,r,p)
    Xcord(R,r,p,t_iter(R,r,p))
    Ycord(R,r,p,t_iter(R,r,p))
    input("Hit enter to close porgram")
    bye()

main()
```